# Appearance of Black Line Under My Donut Like A Shadow (photo attached)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

This is the image with the black lining under my icing:

[image: donut and icing]

I rendered this with Cycles. What have I done wrong? I used the Solidify modifier on my icing and a Subsurf modifier.

[image]

Comment: You are going to have to be a bit more explicit, as far I can tell there is nothing wrong here.

Comment: Is it ok. I was thinking every time that it was wrong.

Comment: One is a bit darker then the other, but that could be the lighting, otherwise no. It's fine.

Comment: sorry for disturbance but how can i fix it

Comment: please reply fast

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, that's just your lighting. Maybe post the .blend on a site like [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)? All I can see in the picture is a shadow made by a the top half being a little bigger than the bottom. :/